# Is there a way to create a FileInput stream from a byte array without storing a file on the file system?

Tags: java, jpa, struts2

I have a Struts2 application with JPA. For this reason the conversion of the formats.
Actually, the Struts2 framework only needs an InputStream, but when I use a ByteArrayInputStream, the file is opened as a preview in the browser. I would like to make the file available for download, so I need a FileInputStream. (I've tried it with this type and it works, too.) I can't put a temporary file on the file system because I'm not allowed to do this.

Comment: 1) What file format are you working with? 2) Can't you just change the application-type of the response?

Comment: I mainly work with XML files, but basically all files should work. You can set the download type in the ContentType, but I have the feeling that this is partly ignored.

Comment: `code` @Action(value = "Download", results = { @Result(name = { SUCCESS, INPUT }, type = "stream", params=  "contentType", "text/file", "inputName", "download", "contentDisposition", "atachement;filename=${uploadFileName}", "bufferSize", "1024" }))

Comment: `contentType` with `application/octet-stream` should cause a download.

Comment: This does not work. I get a preview too. It works only with a FileInputStream.

Comment: @Ponferson what preview? The contents of the file?

Comment: For example, when I select an image file, I see the image file in the browser window. The same applies to an XML file or other files.

Comment: I used the ContentType application/octet-stream, it did not work. So I tried around a bit and it works when I use the ContentType application/file in combination with a FileInputStream.

Comment: @user9093464 it has nothing to do with the type of stream.  It looks like you have typo in your contentDisposition.  It should be "attachment" instead of "attachement"